# React Route Component TypeError: history is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use the React Route component to specify my routing configuration. This is basically what I'm doing:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRouter.Router>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
        </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>,
    document.querySelector("#container")
);
```

[Complete version in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/72306/)

The above results in a Type Error:

> TypeError: history is undefined

Everything is inside a `text/babel` script tag which resides in the `body` of the html document. I'm importing `ReactRouter` by adding the following script tag to the `head` of the document:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script>
```

My application works fine when not using `ReactRouter`. That is, the following code doesn't result in a Type Error:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.querySelector("#container")
);
```

Am I using the component wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post your code on JSFiddle? Or try using non-minified version of react router, may be the error would be more meaningfull

Comment: @Nomad, I've added a link to JSFiddle. Now I'm using the non-minified version of react router and the error says that history is undefined. See updated version of my question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You need to pass history as prop in `<ReactRouter.Router>`. See here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-routef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `history` for `ReactRouter`, it can be `browserHistory` or `hashHistory` depends on your structure. See more information in [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md)

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
        </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>,
    document.querySelector("#container")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>`